# How to iterate values in statements?

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist, textview

I have declared a number of `TextViews` and named them title2, title3,...,title9 and txt2, txt3,..., txt9.
I have the `if` statement below that populates the `TextViews` `title2` and `txt2` and sets their visibility, depending on the data at a given position in some arrays.

```
        if (title2Txt.get(position) != null) {
            int titleId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(titleArray2.get(position),
                    "string", context.getPackageName());
            String txt = txtArray2.get(position);

            title2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            title2.setText(titleId);
            txt2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            txt2.setText(txt);

            if (titleTypeArray2.get(position) == 0) {
                title2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9e9e9e"));
            } else {
                title2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9ccc65"));
            }
        } else {
            title2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            txt2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Right now I have to do this exact code block for all the respective `TextViews`, from 2 to 9, only that the value of the digits (everywhere you see a "2") iterate in every case, ie, 2, then 3, then 4, to 9.

Is there a way to make an iterative statement that will auto-increment these digits in the statements of this code block, so that it simply iterates over the block to populate the TextViews title2-9 and txt2-9 respectively?

I thought of possibly using:

```
int counter = 2;
while (counter < 10) {
...
counter++;
}
```

together with [`Pattern`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), but I'm new to programming and honestly don't really know what `Pattern` really is, nor if and/or how to use it.

Your help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by declaring two arrays of `TextView` instead of declaring 10 of them one by one. Something like this:

```
TextView [] titles = new TextView[10];
TextView [] otherTextViews = new TextView[10];
```

And then you can traverse through these whichever way you like, be it a `for`, `while`, `foreach` loop or whatever. Simply access say the 3rd title `TextView` with `titles[2]` (because array index begins at 0, so 0th index is the 1st element).

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for taking the time to help me. Alright, I think I see how to do what you say. What about the name substitution for the arrays, since title2 `textview` needs to get a value from the titleArray2 `array` and txt2 `textview` needs to get a value from the txtArray2 `array` and so on?

Comment: Yup, I got that part, thanks. I mean for the variables `titleId` and `txt`. How would I make it iterate to take values from titleArray2, then titleArray3 to 9 and txtArray2, then txtArray3 to 9?

Comment: I mean something that will kind of perform an iteration like: `String txt = "txtArray" + counter + ".get(position)";`

Comment: With Vucko's solution you wouldn't need this. Instead of referencing it as txtArray2 or txtArray3 you would access it as txtArray[1] or txtArray[2].

Comment: @InferKNOX exactly what MobileDeveloper said. You'd have a loop, and you'd reference them as `titles[2], titles[3], ..., titles[8]` (this is for titles from 3-9 (since as I said, difference in index starting with 0).

Comment: Ah, I get it! I also made string arrays from `titleArray2`, `txtArray2` and an integer array from `titleType2`, to correlate with the `TextView` arrays and all works perfectly. Thank you so much to you both!